# Insert and train an additional layer between trained lstm layers and output layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, pre-trained-model

Here is what I wanna do:

I want to use some transfer learning techniques to deal with sequence problems:
  First use dataset_1 to train a lstm model, 
  Second insert another lstm layer before the output layer, 
  and then use dataset_2 to only train the newly adding layer, and the variables of other layers are imported from the first training stage and remain unchanged

here's the problem, the existing methods all require the variable name of weight/bias when restoring the pre-trained model. And I want to use the fuction `tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(*)` in my [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py).However, the function is a black box and unable to obtain concrete variable names. How can I realize the idea?

Comment: I would restore the first model as it is, I would stop the gradients on its outputs (`tf.stop_gradients()`) and then I would add the new layer.

Comment: the first model is composed of FC layer_1 -> LSTM layer_1 -> FC layer_2, I want insert another LSTM layer between the LSTM layer1 and FC layer_2 rather than after the FC layer_2

Comment: In this case, you have two possibilities: a) restore the entire graph from the .meta and get the output tensor of LSTM-Layer1 (but you should rewrite your layer2) b) use functions to create layer, pass names to layers, so that the naming would be always the same, rebuild your model and finally saver.restore() the variables.